# What is the actual content of a changeset?

Tags: deployment, change-set

What does a changset actually hold when it is created?

Is it a list of components to upload so that when it is uploaded, the current version of components in the changeset are uploaded or does it hold a copy of the components as they were at the time it was included into the changeset?
So that a subsequent alteration to a component is not relflected in the content of the changeset when it is uploaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A changeset initially contains a reference to the components it contains. **It is only when the change set is deployed a metadata "snapshot" of those components will be made and contained in the change set.**

This is why you can no longer edit a deployed change set, once in this mode any changes to your configuration shouldn't alter the content of the changeset.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, thats what i thought, but did you mean to say "It is only when the change set is deployed ..." or is it more correct to say " It is only when the change set is uploaded.."?

Comment: Euh yes I guess you're right. I consider uploading  deploying from a  source org perspective ( to target org), and consider that separate from deploying on the target org ( applying the changes).

Comment: Okay, just to be clear then, part of the reson i am asking this is because it is not possible to deploy a cganeset in a chain, if from Dev to Test and then from Test to Prod. It has to go from Dev to Test & when all okay from Dev to Prod. So if i write a trigger in Dev and package it (into changeset A) and upload and deploy to the Test environment where it sits for a month while it gets tested, qa'd etc and then approved to go to Prod without further chnges required.  Cont'd on next comment.

Comment: Yes, once you've uploaded the change set to Test, it won't change and you can re-use it to upload to Prod. Any changes in the mean time to your code or configuration will not impact the change set.

Comment: Cont'd from my previous comment - If during that time as a result of a separate set of requirments the trigger code in Dev is further altered then it still won't alter what gets uploaded and deployed to Prod when Changeset A gets the green light to go to Prod? Samuel, are you saying the code in Changeset A will not reflect the changes subsequent to its first upload, (which is what we want)?

Comment: Yes. at the first time change set A gets uploaded, it gets locked and the code/config inside it is no longer a reference-to, but a snapshot-of. The snapshot can not change in between uploads.